# Looking for a solution to $\int_0^\infty \cos(\ln(x))e^{-x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I tried to evaluate
$$I=\int_0^\infty \cos(\ln(x))e^{-x}dx$$
$$J=\int_0^\infty \sin(\ln(x))e^{-x}dx$$
and got $$I=\Re(\Gamma(1+i))$$ $$J=\Im(\Gamma(1+i))$$
just using the fact that $\cos(\ln(x))=\Re(x^i)$ and $\sin(\ln(x))=\Im(x^i)$.
The problem is that I couldn't find a closed form for $\Gamma(1+i)$, and so the two integrals aren't "solved". I would like suggestions to solve them without using gamma.

Comment: Why should $\Gamma(1+i)$ have a clean closed form ([Wolfram certainly doesn't think so](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Gamma%281%2Bi%29)), or the integrals for that matter? Up to your intended use, this would be a perfectly valid solution in my eyes. ***Most*** integrals can't be evaluated cleanly.

Comment: Does it help, if you consider cos and sin by it's exponential forms?

Comment: @PrincessEev Im just asking if someone is able to evaluate the integrals in some other way than with gamma functions. If someone does it we get a closed form for $\Gamma(1+i)$ for free.

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A212877 and https://oeis.org/A212878 .

Comment: The OEIS has a limit formula for the [argument](https://oeis.org/A212880), so we can write it as $i!=\sqrt{\pi\text{csch}(\pi)}e^{\arg(i!)}$

Comment: @J.G. No, I mean this from the “argument” link: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\cot^{-1}(k)-\ln(n)\right)$